# Getting error message "Code Recommenders cannot download its model repository index"

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse works fine, but now, periodically a message box comes up saying

> Code Recommenders cannot download its model repository index

What does this mean?

Comment: Which version of eclipse and Java are you using? Is it connected with this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=519862 ?

Comment: VER  Photon Release (4.8.0)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you go to "Preferences"/"Code Recommenders"/"Models" you will see some Repository URL's listed. In my case it is `http://download.eclipse.org/recommenders/models/photon/`.

But when you call that URL you will get a `404` since the *site* has been archived in July 2019.

So this URL beeing invalid causes the Error. Since the URL is not available is seems save to `silently ignore` it, as beeing suggested in the error-dialog.

As beeing said in the [Reviews on eclipse Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-code-recommenders?mpc=true&mpc_state=) the project is archived due to lack of comitting developers. And you may find an archived last version here: https://repo.eclipse.org/content/shadows/releases.unzip/org/eclipse/recommenders/stable/

Answer (score 17):

As written in the other answer, Code Recommenders has been archived due to lack of active maintainers, see [this forum post](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1099870/).

Therefore when the plugin tries to download the models it fails because the site does not exist anymore, and you will see the following error dialog:
[image: Code Recommenders error dialog]

While you could choose to ignore this download failure in the future, I am not sure if Code Recommenders actually does anything without its models (please correct me if I am wrong), so at this point you could also uninstall the plugin.

OR, you could download the models manually:

1. Download the archived data of Code Recommenders: https://archive.eclipse.org/archived_projects/recommenders.tgz (9.7 GB!)
2. Extract `recommenders/downloads/models/photon`
3. In Eclipse: Open "Window" > "Preferences" > "Code Recommenders" > "Models"
4. Remove the existing download.eclipse.org entry
5. Add a new entry with a `file` URI pointing to the folder you extracted earlier. Note that you have to percent escape the URI, e.g.
   `C:\Program Files\eclipse\recommenders` becomes `file:///C:/Program%20Files/eclipse/recommenders`
6. Click the "Apply" (and Close) button

Note however, that since you downloaded the files locally and there is no active development, you won't get recommendations for new Java features.

Comment: Re: "at this point you could also uninstall the plugin": In Eclipse Photon w/Oomph, actually fully uninstalling causes Oomph to complain about missing dependencies and ask to reinstall them. It is easier to ignore download failure with the dialog -- or to deactivate autodownload in Preferences > Code Recommenders > Models > [_] "enable auto-download".

Comment: I work in an offline environment. I simple removed the existing repo entry and I can work so.

Answer (score 6):

I don't want any of you to have to download 10 gigabytes like in @Marcono1234's solution, so I re-uploaded version-specific code recommender models to mega.nz and shared them here.

1. Download the code recommenders

For Eclipse Juno users: https://mega.nz/file/tuRFGYQD#zB_mq6XwO7nupLqMDRWQRnnhD3-FAgT3ijtDQyGvjFE

For Eclipse Kelper users: https://mega.nz/file/NjxXFYyb#uwpP3zxESL02prgTimhDL35xPXMnDkbDwzrhJG1rcgc

For Eclipse Luna users: https://mega.nz/file/02g1DASB#3GSzaKtFSGsxhdnNx2aX47DoD22ZZ6aUu9eXTUvoxKg

For Eclipse Mars users:
https://mega.nz/file/xnQDTQLC#wmA0cfL_ChVHuQ9r0Mo_Js3ef_eDyg2yU6Z2_JTUPbE

For Eclipse Neon users: https://mega.nz/file/siBF1QYC#aVfX3-FS5sNfLmRqCPg6eUaovQPpEkMqIPWugv3E3qk

For Eclipse Oxygen users: https://mega.nz/file/9nAjUITQ#BpQ4HagdlrfZOelW8jqVgJWI-5QlA38JLCGpGoMbWpc

For Eclipse Photon users: https://mega.nz/file/oq5klCBR#vB8f0vmPH3gaYGwkw7U1SVThW5IxKMuvhBughN-sJi4

2. Extract it to any folders you want (in my case, c:\workspaces\eclipse\recommenders)
3. In Eclipse: Open "Window" > "Preferences" > "Code Recommenders" > "Models"
4. Remove the default entry
5. Add a file URL to the path you extracted your code recommender model. In my case, it's file://workspaces/eclipse/recommenders.
6. Click the "Apply" (and Close) button
7. Enjoy!